# swift error 'expression type 'HKAnchoredObjectQuery' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: xcode, debugging, healthkit

I'm getting an error "expression type 'HKAnchoredObjectQuery' is ambiguous without more content" on the healthkit code, for the line "let heartRateQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType, predicate: nil, anchor: anchor, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, sampleObjects, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in"

The code is copy-pasted from a sample project, which runs without errors on this line, into my project where it now brings this error. I'm a beginner- would appreciate your tips.

The code:

```
  func createHeartRateStreamingQuery(workoutStartDate: NSDate) -> HKQuery? {
    // adding predicate will not work
    //let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(workoutStartDate, endDate: nil, options: HKQueryOptions.None)

    guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate) else { return nil }

    let heartRateQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType, predicate: nil, anchor: anchor, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, sampleObjects, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
        guard let newAnchor = newAnchor else {return}
        self.anchor = newAnchor
        self.updateHeartRate(sampleObjects)
```

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi @Philip thanks for writing. no solution as yet.

Answer (score 2):

This one drove me crazy, I ran into the same issue. I think if you change your heartRateQuery initialization line to this it'll work:

```
let heartRateQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType, predicate: nil, anchor: anchor, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), resultsHandler: { (query, sampleObjects, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) in
        //Do anchor code here
        guard let newAnchor = newAnchor else {return}
        self.anchor = newAnchor
        self.updateHeartRate(sampleObjects)
    })
```

They removed the parenthesis after the limit and use a named parameter (resultsHandler) for the closure that defines the results. You also don't need the "-> Void" code anymore. This is for Swift 3, BTW.

The error is misleading in that it seems like it can't determine the class. In my case since my query is a property that's initialized as nil and thus an optional, I assumed that was the issue. The real issue is that it's ambiguous because the constructor incorrect and because it's incorrect it cannot determine  what the object returned should be.

If it helps further this is some of my code that works:

```
self.acQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: sampleType,
                                         predicate: pred,
                                         anchor: self.acAnchor,
                                         limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit),
                                         resultsHandler: { (query, newSamples, deletedSamples, newAnchor, error) in

                                            self.updateHeartRates(newSamples: newSamples, deletedSamples: deletedSamples, newAnchor: newAnchor, error: error);
                                            })
```

Good luck!